# Calculate volume between sphere $r=R$ and plane $z=\frac{R}{2}$ using cylndical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Plug in $z=\frac{R}{2}$ into sphere equation in cartesian gives the projection on $XY$ plane:

$x^2+y^2=(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}R)^2$

In cylindical that means  $0\leq r \leq\frac{\sqrt3}{2}R $ and $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

For $z$, set $\theta$ and $r$ constant, then if we draw a line parallel to $z$ axis, we see that the sphere is up and the plane is down (this is how i've been taught to set $z$ bound). Then from sphere equation and converting to cylindical $\frac{R}{2}\leq z \leq \sqrt{R^2-r^2}$.

However when I calculated the triple integral $V=\int\int\int rdrdzd\theta$ with these bounds the volume is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take slices of the sphere parallel to the $xy$ plane of the sphere between $z = -R$ and $ z = \dfrac{R}{2} $

The area of the slice is

$ A(z) = \pi ( R^2 - z^2 ) $

Therefore, the integral is

$ V = \displaystyle \pi \int_{-R}^{R/2} \pi (R^2 - z^2) dz $

which is a very easy integral to evaluate.  From the above equation, we get

$ V = \pi \left[ R^2 z - \dfrac{1}{3} z^3 \right]_{-R}^{R/2} $

Finally, we get

$ V = \pi \left[ \dfrac{R^3}{2} - \dfrac{R^3}{24} + R^3 - \dfrac{R^3}{3} \right] $

And this simplifies to

$ V = \dfrac{ 9 \pi R^3 }{8} $

Answer (score 1):

Equation of a sphere in cylindrical coordinates

$$ r^2+z^2= R^2 \tag1 $$

$$ V= \int \pi r^2 dz= \pi \int _{R/2} ^R (R^2-z^2) dz \tag 2 $$

You can finish the integration. ( Ans$ \dfrac{5\pi R^3}{24}$ )

$r=R$ is a sphere in spherical coordinates. $r=R$ is a cylinder in cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Why $\frac{R}{2}\leq z \leq R$ and not  $\frac{R}{2}\leq z \leq \sqrt{R^2-r^2}$? both seem correct to me, that's my problem with this question

Comment: Integrand $\pi r^2$ equals  $\pi (R^2-z^2)$ because  $ R^2=r^2+z^2 $. The upper/lower  limits of $z$ interval  *cannot* change.